# How to add a database retrieved value custom claim to JWT Token using ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

In AppHost.Configure I have the following code:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new JwtAuthProvider
        {
            HashAlgorithm = "HS256",
            RequireSecureConnection = requireSecureConnection,
            AuthKeyBase64 = _configuration["AuthSettings:JwtAuthKeyBase64"],//Settings.Value.JwtAuthKeyBase64,
            ExpireTokensIn        = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireTokensIn"].ToDouble()),  // JWT Token Expiry
            ExpireRefreshTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireRefreshTokensIn"].ToDouble()), // Refresh Token Expiry,
            CreatePayloadFilter = (payload,session) => {
                    payload["ZipCode"] = "value_from_database_for_user";
            }
        },
        new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of User/Pass
    }));
```

The above code is standard [ServiceStack JwtAuthProvider](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) code.

You can see in the above code that the implementation for the anonymous function bound to `CreatePayloadFilter` would like to retrieve a value from the database, the user's ZipCode is the value and add that as a custom claim to the token.

For many obvious reasons, implementing the retrieval of the user's ZipCode in the AppHost is not easy, elegant or system/architecturally sound. Also it is not even possible, as I will not have the UserId, AppHost is just startup configuration code ran when the service starts.

You can also see in the above code that I have implemented a `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider`, I can load session data for the logged in user in `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider` and ServiceStack will map the session values to hydrate the appropriate JWT claims but I cannot add a custom claim via the ServiceStack session object, here is the implementation of `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider`:

```
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService,
        string userName, string password)
    {
        return true;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService,
        IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens,
        Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        //Fill IAuthSession with data you want to retrieve in the app eg:
        session.FirstName = "some_firstname_from_db";
        session.LastName = "some_lastname_from_db";
        session.Roles = new List<string> {"role1", "role2"};
        session.Permissions = new List<string> { "permission1", "permission2" };
        session.Email = "test@test.com";
        session.AuthProvider = "credentials";

        //...

        //Call base method to Save Session and fire Auth/Session callbacks:
        return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

        //Alternatively avoid built-in behavior and explicitly save session with
        //authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
        //return null;
    }
}
```

**How can I add a custom claim to the ServiceStack framework created JWT, the value of that claim coming from the database and this implementation of this code not be function binding in AppHost.cs where I do not even have the UserId to retrieve the value anyways?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a Custom UserSession to hold the additional metadata, you can tell ServiceStack to use your Custom Session when you register the AuthFeature, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(), ...)
```

After which you can cast the UserSession to your `CustomUserSession` to access the additional properties.

To add [additional metadata to the JWT Token](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#modifying-the-payload) you'd use `CreatePayloadFilter` to add the data to the JWT Token and a corresponding `PopulateSessionFilter` to populate your Custom UserSession with the additional data.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to provide my final code for this even though @mythz provided the answer:

The `CustomerUserSession`:

```
[DataContract]
public class CustomUserSession: AuthUserSession
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

The `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider` because I have a legacy db with all account info:

```
public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService,
        string userName, string password)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService,
        IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens,
        Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        var customUserSession = (CustomUserSession) session;
        //Fill IAuthSession with data you want to retrieve in the app eg:
        customUserSession.FirstName = "some_firstname_from_db";
        customUserSession.LastName = "some_lastname_from_db";
        customUserSession.Roles = new List<string> {"role1", "role2"};
        customUserSession.Permissions = new List<string> { "permission1", "permission2" };
        customUserSession.Email = "test@test.com";
        customUserSession.AuthProvider = "credentials";
        customUserSession.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        customUserSession.ZipCode = "92123";


        //Call base method to Save Session and fire Auth/Session callbacks:
        return base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);
    }
```

And my AppHost adding of the ServiceStack `AuthFeature`:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new JwtAuthProvider
        {
            HashAlgorithm = "HS256",
            RequireSecureConnection = requireSecureConnection,
            AuthKeyBase64 = _configuration["AuthSettings:JwtAuthKeyBase64"],//Settings.Value.JwtAuthKeyBase64,
            ExpireTokensIn        = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireTokensIn"].ToDouble()),  // JWT Token Expiry
            ExpireRefreshTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromHours(_configuration["AuthSettings:ExpireRefreshTokensIn"].ToDouble()), // Refresh Token Expiry,
            CreatePayloadFilter = (payload,session) => {
                    payload["zipCode"] = ((CustomUserSession)session).ZipCode;
            },
            PopulateSessionFilter = (session, token, req) => {
                ((CustomUserSession) session).ZipCode = token["zipCode"];
            }
        },
        new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider() //HTML Form post of User/Pass
    }));
```